# what does head.misc entity represents?

Tags: html

i have been given the head element declaration as follow

```
<!ENTITY % head.misc "(script|style|meta|link|object)*">
<!ELEMENT head (%head.misc;,((title, %head.misc;, (base, %head.misc;)?) | (base, %head.misc;, (title, %head.misc;))))>
```

and being ask to describe "what the head.misc entity represents?"

all I could find was DTD files using head.misc 
and also a brief explanation saying that :
"And elements of head.misc are only allowed to be children of the HEAD element. So STYLE is only allowed to be child of the HEAD element"
but it doesn't seems like complete answer.

should I say it represents which elements should only be used in head element tag?

Comment: The element head rule tells us what's allowed within head. It tells us nothing about what's allowed or forbidden elsewhere. So we don't know from those two rules whether STYLE is limited to being *only* allowed to be child of the HEAD element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some notation explanations:

- `%head.misc;` -- just a reference to the entity defined above, so, you can replace it with expression `(script|style|meta|link|object)*`
- `,` -- comma seems to be a list separator
- `()` -- brackets are grouping thing, as in regex
- `?` -- question mark is a zero-or-one quantifier (i.e. thing to the left can be there 0 or 1 times, in other words it is optional, but limited to one instance)
- `*` -- asterisk is a zero-or-more quantifier (thing to the left can be there 0, 1, 2, or any other number of times -- optional, but not limited to one instance)
- `|` -- bar character is `or` -- i.e. either left or right part of the grouping, but not both (there can be more than 2 parts, of course, the principle is the same)

So, expression behind `head.misc` can be interpreted like this:

- `head.misc` is any number of any of these elements, in any combinations, (including empty case, i.e. zero elements):

  - script
  - style
  - meta
  - link
  - object

> should I say it represents which elements should only be used in head element tag?

No, as the next statement adds two more possible elements -- `title` and `base`. As far as I can understand, `head` can be either this :

- zero or more `script/style/meta/link/object` tags
- followed by `title`
- followed by zero or more `script/style/meta/link/object` tags
- optionally followed by `base` tag and zero or more zero or more `script/style/meta/link/object` tags

Or this:

- zero or more `script/style/meta/link/object` tags
- followed by `base`
- followed by zero or more `script/style/meta/link/object` tags
- followed by `title` tag and zero or more zero or more `script/style/meta/link/object` tags

So, it seems two rules together express the following about tags inside `head`:

- there can be any number (including zero) of `script/style/meta/link/object` tags
- there must be exactly one `title` tag anywhere
- there must be zero or one `base` tag anywhere